# ListView item behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

i'm trying to achieve single item selection behavior like in Windows 8 startscreen - Item selection on little drag and click on tap - how can i achieve this i need to prevent selection on leftclick?

I have this so far:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

And the style to prevent vertical and horizontal scroll on Scrollviewer built into listview:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" IsZoomChainingEnabled="False" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="False" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <ItemsPresenter HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the IsItemClickEnabled property. Once you enable this behavior you can subscribe to the ItemClick event.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. But just tested on tablet on little drag it is not selecting i thought it is normal behavior but it seems i have to do some modifying also?

Comment: You should be able to select by dragging the element in the opposite direction of the scrollviewer. But I see above that you have modified the internal scroll of the control, so this might not apply to your scenario